# Detecting trends in values of images' metadata in image collection using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image, evi

I am beginner in javascript and in GEE. So far I made a script for calculating the mean EVI value of images inside an image collection and adding the value as a metadata for each picture. Now I would like to compare images next to each other and check to see if any change in trend occurs. For example, if two consecutive pictures (sorted by time ascending) have increasing values for evi(e.g the first picture has an evi value of 20 and the 2nd one has an evi value of 30) and the 3rd picture has a decreasing value compared to the 2nd one (e.g 25, 10 or whatever), I would like to print a message that a change in trend has been discovered. Here it's what I have so far:

```
var S2images = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2022-05-01', '2022-08-31')
    .filterBounds(table)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 2));
   
    print(S2images,'Sentinel 2 images');

function evi(image) {
  var expression = '2.5 * (NIR - RED)/(NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1)'; 
  var evind = image.expression({
    expression: expression,
    map: {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
      'BLUE': image.select('B2')
    }
}).rename('EVI');
  return image.addBands(evind);

}

var imagesEVI = S2images.map(evi);
print(imagesEVI,"the image collection with the evi band added to the bands");

var getStats = function(image) {
  
  var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean();

  var stats1 = ee.Image(image).reduceRegion({
    reducer: reducers,
    geometry: table,
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var dict = {
  stats: stats1
};
  return ee.Image(image).set(stats1);

};

var statistics = imagesEVI.select('EVI').map(getStats);

print(statistics,"statistics");
```